# Does android app update change the UID?

Tags: android

App UID is determined by the package manager, if i take an update version app from playstore, does it necessarily change the app UID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally the Linux UID assigned to your app does not change after an upgrade to your app.

One exception is if you choose to alter the `android:sharedUserId` attribute. Once an app is installed, if you change the `android:sharedUserId` attribute (including giving it a value where you did not have one before), the app *will* get a new Linux UID... but your files will be owned by the old UID. This is why I **strongly** encourage developers to not use `android:sharedUserId`.